# Why does printf("%02x"...) change output?

Tags: c, hash, printf, sha1

```
/*HASHING*/
unsigned char *do_hashing(unsigned char *buffer){
    unsigned char outbuffer[20];
    unsigned char output[20];
    SHA1(buffer, strlen(buffer), outbuffer);

    for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {
        output[i]=outbuffer[i];
    }

    printf("The hash: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
          printf("%02x ", outbuffer[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    return output;
}
/*HASHING*/
```

Why does this function produce different output (wrong one) if I remove printf-function. For example:

```
./ftest
The hash: a1 2a 9c 6e 60 85 75 6c d8 cb c9 98 c9 42 76 a7 f4 8d be 73 
The hash: a1 2a 9c 6e 60 85 75 6c d8 cb c9 98 c9 42 76 a7 f4 8d be 73 
=with for-loop print

./ftest

The hash: 6c 08 40 00 00 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
=without for-loop print
```

I have not included the main-function or #includes in this case because error occurs inside this function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are returning a pointer to a local variable `unsigned char output[20];`,

The variable does not exist after the function ends causing undefined behavor.

Comment: More specifically, returning **a pointer to** a local variable.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, you are returning local pointer (that is placed on stack). This causes an **undefined behavior**.

If you want to do it, please use `malloc()` function to allocate memory in heap.

```
unsigned char* output = malloc(20*sizeof(unsigned char));
```

But don't forget to call `free()` to free the allocated memory, otherwise you'll get a memory leak.